# How to call a variable declared in another perl file?

Tags: windows, perl

I've **script1.pl** and **script2.pl**. I'm looking for making *script2.pl* able to call the value of `$string` from *script1.pl*.

**script1.pl**

```
$string="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9";
$cmd="perl \"My\\File\\Path\\script2.pl\"";
system ($cmd);
```

**script2.pl**

```
print $string;
```

**Note**: I'm using perl for Windows.

Comment: Here's a hint: you need to make script2.pl accept and use command-line arguments. You can then pass in $string as an argument to script2.pl.

Comment: Also, it would help us to help you if you can show us what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#ARGV1

Comment: Your approach is a little clumsy. If you give us more information, such as showing us the whole of `script1.pl` and `script2.pl` then I am sure we can help yo to do this better

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is use a module. See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html).

In your case, you can use [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). Make sure that `require` files return truth by adding `1`.

script1.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

our $string = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9";
our $cmd = "perl \"My\\File\\Path\\script2.pl\"";
system ($cmd);

1;
```

script2.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;    
use vars qw($string);

require "script1.pl";

print $string, "\n";
```

Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9
```

Comment: script2.pl requires script1.pl which executes script2.pl. My head hurts.

Comment: Even my head is hurting, :) but OP has mentioned `$cmd` in that way, don't know what exactly OP is trying. I just wanted to tell him/her how to call a variable from one script to another.

Answer (score 0):

While you can make that work, you're much better off passing in the variable as command line arguments, or if there's a lot of data, to STDIN.

```
# script1.pl
my $cmd = qq[$^X "My\\File\\Path\\script2.pl"];
my @words = qw[word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9];
system $cmd, @words;

# script2.pl
print join ", ", @ARGV;
```

This doesn't scale well. You're better off rewriting script2.pl as a library and calling a function.

```
# mylibrary.pl
sub print_stuff {
    print join ", ", @_;
}

# script1.pl
require 'mylibrary.pl';

print_stuff(qw[word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9]);
```

For a handful of functions this will work fine. Eventually you'll want to look into [writing modules](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblob.perl.org%2Fbooks%2Fbeginning-perl%2F3145_Chap10.pdf).